How to have a pop-up for a download on my navbar?
I am looking to have a pop-up when someone clicks on my download button on my navbar, but I have been having problems when trying to make it work.
Here's an example website. (rubberduckvba.com) I can't link it, it gets marked as spam.
I know I am asking for someone to just write the code, but even just tips would be great =)
I have tried to make a div for each and make it hidden or visible depending on if the user clicked it, but I could not get js to recognize the div I wanted.


fetch('navbar.html').then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
  let oldelem = document.querySelector("script#navbar");
  let newelem = document.createElement("div");
  newelem.innerHTML = text;
  oldelem.parentNode.replaceChild(newelem, oldelem); // Now that the navbar is loaded, set the active link
  const currentPage = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav a.nav-link");
  navLinks.forEach(link => {
    if (link.getAttribute("data-page") === currentPage) {
      link.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});

marked.use({
  breaks: true
})
async function fetchReadme() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RanchoDVT/Comp-V5/dev/README.md');
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('README not found');
    const text = await response.text();
    document.getElementById('readme-content').innerHTML = marked.parse(text);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching README:', error);
  }
}

async function fetchChangelog() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RanchoDVT/Comp-V5/dev/changelog.md');
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Changelog not found');
    const text = await response.text();
    document.getElementById('changelog-content').innerHTML = marked.parse(text);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching changelog:', error);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (document.getElementById('readme-content')) {
    fetchReadme();
  }
  if (document.getElementById('changelog-content')) {
    fetchChangelog();
  }
});


// I hate js, why do I need a DOM loader check?
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var configForm = document.getElementById('config-form');
  var copyButton = document.getElementById('copy-button');
  var configOutput = document.getElementById('config-output');


  if (configForm) {
    configForm.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Function to get the latest release version from GitHub
      async function getLatestReleaseVersion() {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/RanchoDVT/Comp-V5/releases/latest', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'JavaScript'
          }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        const latestTag = data.tag_name;
        return latestTag;
      }
      const formData = new FormData(event.target);
      config = `MOTOR_CONFIG
{
  FRONT_LEFT_MOTOR
  {
      PORT=${formData.get('front_left_port')}
      GEAR_RATIO=${formData.get('front_left_gear_ratio')}
      REVERSED=${formData.has('front_left_reversed')}
  }
  FRONT_RIGHT_MOTOR
  {
      PORT=${formData.get('front_right_port')}
      GEAR_RATIO=${formData.get('front_right_gear_ratio')}
      REVERSED=${formData.has('front_right_reversed')}
  }
  REAR_LEFT_MOTOR
  {
      PORT=${formData.get('rear_left_port')}
      GEAR_RATIO=${formData.get('rear_left_gear_ratio')}
      REVERSED=${formData.has('rear_left_reversed')}
  }
  REAR_RIGHT_MOTOR
  {
      PORT=${formData.get('rear_right_port')}
      GEAR_RATIO=${formData.get('rear_right_gear_ratio')}
      REVERSED=${formData.has('rear_right_reversed')}
  }
  INERTIAL
  {
      PORT=${formData.get('inertial_port')}
  }
  Rear_Bumper
  {
      PORT=${formData.get('rear_bumper_port')}
  }
  PRINTLOGO=${formData.has('print_logo')}
  LOGTOFILE=${formData.has('log_to_file')}
  MAXOPTIONSSIZE=${formData.get('max_options_size')}
  POLLINGRATE=${formData.get('polling_rate')}
  CTRLR1POLLINGRATE=${formData.get('ctrlr1_polling_rate')}
  VERSION=${await getLatestReleaseVersion()}
}`
      completeCheck = true;

      configOutput.textContent = config;

      // Show the copy button once the config is generated
      copyButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
    });
  }

  if (copyButton) {
    copyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (configOutput.textContent) {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(configOutput.textContent)
          .then(() => {
            console.debug('Config copied to clipboard!');
            const button =
              document.querySelector('copyButton');
            copyButton.innerHTML = 'Copied! ✅';
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error copying text (Thats one rare error!): ', err);
          });
      }
    });
  }
});
html {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #38444d;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #38444d;
  backdrop-filter: 8;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li a,
.nav-link.dropbtn {
  /* Add .nav-link.dropbtn */
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(170, 96, 36);
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

nav li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li:last-child a {
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-right: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  background-color: lightslategrey;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  background-color: lightslategrey;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  /* Remove borders */
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  background-color: lightslategrey;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

input {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin
}

select {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.config-output {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* Ensures text wraps properly (Who thought this was a good idea???)*/
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Handles horizontal overflow (Same with this!!!)*/
}

button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

a {
  color: #7bbaeb;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script id="navbar" src="main.js"></script>
<!-- navbar fetched from site -->
<nav>
  <li><a class="nav-link" data-page="index.html" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" data-page="projects.html" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Voidless7125/Comp-V5">Comp V3</a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/RanchoDVT/Vex-SDK">Custom SDK</a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://ranchodvt.github.io/Comp-V5/">This website!</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link">Downloads (WIP popup)</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a>Comp_V3 Stable</a>
      <a>Comp_V3 Pre-Release</a>
      <a>Custom SDK Stable</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav-link" data-page="features.html" href="features.html">Features</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link" data-page="contact.html" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float: right;"><a class="nav-link" data-page="about.html" href="about.html">About</a></li>
</nav>
<!-- end navbar -->
<div id="readme-content"></div>
<footer>Copyright © 2024 Voidless7125</footer>



Here's an example of what I am looking for when a user clicks on a download on my navbar:


https://ranchodvt.github.io/Comp-V5/index.html
https://rubberduckvba.com/
Are the links.

I made you a snippet. Please modify it to a [mcve] if needed

About 90% of the code can be removed here. And you need a test for DOMContentLoaded to not run a script that needs elements to be present before they are.

What will the popup do? Ask if they really want to download some code from some site or subscribe to your newsletter? Please visit [ask]

Sorry about me posting all my code, thanks for letting me know.

The pop up is just to confirm if a user wants to download my code, I just added an example image.

I have been having problems when trying to make it work <-- Help us help you. What exact problems are you having?

I have not been able to make JS see the div I want to modify, and I assume it is because my navbar is on a separate HTML file. Sorry for not making it clear.


You only need one DOMContentLoaded. 2. Move the navbar event listener to the nearest STATIC container. Looks like that would be document in your case


Something like document.addEventListener('click',(e) => { const tgt = e.target.closest('nav .dropdown-content'); if (!tgt) return; if (confirm('are you sure')) return true; else e.preventDefault(); });

@mplungjan Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "Move the navbar event listener ", your talking about the JavaScript code, not the HTML code right? If your talking about JS, you want me to put it in the DomLoaderCheck right? (I missed the 2nd comment you just posted, reading it rn)

Just read and tried using it, nice.

We just need now to make it into a div rather than a browser pop-up.

Here's my fixing up of it:


async function getLatestRelease(repo) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/releases/latest`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.tag_name;
}

function downloadFile(url, filename) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

async function showPopup(type) {
    let popupText = '';
    let downloadLink = '';

    if (type === 'dev') {
        popupText = 'Thank you for downloading Comp_V3 *dev*! This download link goes to the Github API. This is the source code. <br> <br> You will need my Custom SDK to use this. Check out my other download in the navbar.';
        downloadLink = 'https://github.com/RanchoDVT/Comp-V5/archive/refs/heads/dev.zip';
        document.getElementById('popup-title').innerText = 'Download Comp-V3 ' + type;
    } else if (type === 'stable') {
        const latestTag = await getLatestRelease('RanchoDVT/Comp-V5');
        popupText = 'Thank you for downloading Comp_V3 stable! This download link goes to the Github API. This is the source code. <br> <br> You will need my Custom SDK to use this. Check out my other download in the navbar.';
        downloadLink = `https://github.com/RanchoDVT/Comp-V5/archive/refs/tags/${latestTag}.zip`;
        document.getElementById('popup-title').innerText = 'Download Comp-V3 ' + type + ' ' + latestTag;
    } else if (type === 'sdk') {
        const latestTag = await getLatestRelease('RanchoDVT/Vex-SDK');
        popupText = 'Thank you for downloading my custom SDK. This is unofficial and in no way affiliated, endorsed, supported, or created by VEX Robotics. <br> <br> You will need this to install my Custom SDK (This) to use my Comp_V3 Program. This modifies Vex\'s robotics extension, so PLEASE don\'t go to them if you have problems with this. Please contact me. <br> <br>There is a PowerShell script for this to make it easier: ';
        popupText += '<a href="https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/RanchoDVT/Vex-SDK/blob/dev/Vex-SDK.updater.ps1">Powershell download</a>';
        document.getElementById('popup-title').innerText = 'Download Custom ' + type + ' ' + latestTag;
        downloadLink = `https://github.com/RanchoDVT/Vex-SDK/archive/refs/tags/${latestTag}.zip`;
    }

    document.getElementById('popup-text').innerHTML = popupText; // Use innerHTML to render HTML content
    document.getElementById('download-link').href = downloadLink;
    document.getElementById('popup').classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add('active');
}


function hidePopup() {
    document.getElementById('popup').classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById('overlay').classList.remove('active');
}
.popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 1000;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.popup.active {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
}

.popup-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}

.popup-header h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: black;
}

.download-btn, .cancel-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.download-btn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.cancel-btn {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 999;
}

.overlay.active {
    display: block;
}
    <nav>
        <li><a class="nav-link" data-page="index.html" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" data-page="projects.html" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Voidless7125/Comp-V5">Comp V3</a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/RanchoDVT/Vex-SDK">Custom SDK</a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://ranchodvt.github.io/Comp-V5/">This website!</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link">Downloads</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a onclick="showPopup('stable')">Comp_V3 Stable</a>
                <a onclick="showPopup('dev')">Comp_V3 Dev</a>
                <a onclick="showPopup('sdk')">Custom SDK Stable</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" data-page="features.html" href="features.html">Features</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" data-page="contact.html" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li style="float: right;"><a class="nav-link" data-page="about.html" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </nav>

    <!-- Pop-Up Structure -->
    <div id="popup" class="popup">
        <div class="popup-header">
            <h2 id="popup-title">Download</h2>
        </div>
        <p id="popup-text"></p>
        <button class="cancel-btn" onclick="hidePopup()">Cancel</button>
        <a id="download-link" class="download-btn" href="#" download>Download</a>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay" class="overlay" onclick="hidePopup()"></div>



